# Angular 7 (click) is not working with [hidden] attribute

Tags: angular, angular7

Angular 7 `(click)` event is not working with `[hidden]` attribute, any reason for this?
this is my sample code

```
<div class="autocomplete-dropdown" [hidden]="!showdeviceDropDown">
    <button *ngFor="let item of devices; let i= index" (click)="Save()" class="btn btn-danger">{{ item.serialNumber }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: show save function

Comment: Save() {
     console.log('Save Button Clicked');
  }

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's because of the "[hidden]"? if you remove it, it works?

Comment: this is working without [hidden] tag

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wi77wq

i just added a stackblitz that works fine with hidden. please share your save function

Comment: Toggle-able hidden and working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtwo8y

Comment: It may happen that you might not have defined `showdeviceDropDown` in your component

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, you probably have a run time error some where else in your code. Debug in the browser or view the errors in the browser console to see why it is not working.

[Working demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ubrnm)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  numOfClicks = 0;
  showdeviceDropDown = true;
  devices = [{serialNumber: '123'}];

  Save(){
    this.numOfClicks++;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div> Showing = {{showdeviceDropDown}}</div>

<div [hidden]="!showdeviceDropDown">
   <button *ngFor="let item of devices; let i= index" (click)="Save()">{{ item.serialNumber }}</button>
</div>

<div> Number of clicks:{{numOfClicks}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ngIf` instead of `hidden` as follows -

```
<div class="autocomplete-dropdown" *ngIf="showdeviceDropDown">
```

Comment: can u create a demo. Or edit this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdkyhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: IT will, yes it will remove from DOM. but once the conditioned get true, it will be attached itself to the dom. it is much more lightweight to the DOM since we are removing element instead of hiding/

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka: Got it, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Not a good way. NgIf should be use only if u want to remove or add component in the dom element itself. If u simply want to hide/show the container better use [hidden]

Answer (score 0):

> Logically your code is perfectly fine. There is nothing to change with your `hidden` also.***Please ensure that you've defined your `showdeviceDropDown` variable in your component & you are checking your output in the console***, because you printed your click event on the console.

Though, if you want to alter your `hidden` attribute, you could simply try replacing it with `[class.d-none]`. So your script will be -

```
<div class="autocomplete-dropdown" [class.d-none]="!showdeviceDropDown">
    <button *ngFor="let item of devices; let i= index" (click)="Save()" class="btn btn-danger">{{ item.serialNumber }}</button>
</div>
```

**Suggestion:** Do use *lower camel case* for your methods & properties. **[Here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#properties-and-methods)**'s a reference to the official style guide.